# Is there any pandas function to merge 3 rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
ABC | NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  PK  KJ
PQR | NaN  NaN  RR  SS    NaN  NaN
MNO | PO   UI   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Needed output:

```
ABC | PO  UI  RR  SS  PK  KJ
```

tried a = abc.combine_first(pqr) 
b= mno.combine_first(a)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of the rows (as code).

Comment: You need to explain the logic behind this. For example, why is the first column `PQR`, and not `ABC`?

Comment: Is "ABC", "PQR", "MNO" column labels or values of the first column (or index column)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take the following sample DataFrame, containing 2 groups
of 3 adjacent rows:

```
      C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   C6
ABC  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   PK   KJ
PQR  NaN  NaN   RR   SS  NaN  NaN
MNO   PO   UI  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
XXX   AA  NaN  NaN  NaN   EE  NaN
XX1  NaN   BB  NaN   DD  NaN  FF1
XX2  NaN  NaN   CC  NaN  NaN  FF2
```

Then proceed as follows:

1. Define a function "cumulating" the content from a group
   of rows:

   ```
   def getFirstValue(grp):
       return grp.reset_index().bfill(axis=0).iloc[0]
   ```
2. Then apply it:

   ```
   df2 = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 3).apply(getFirstValue)
   ```
3. And a couple of "finishing" operations:

   ```
   df2.set_index('index', inplace=True)
   df2.index.name = None
   df2.columns.name = None
   ```

The result is:

```
     C1  C2  C3  C4  C5   C6
ABC  PO  UI  RR  SS  PK   KJ
XXX  AA  BB  CC  DD  EE  FF1
```